# Use flexbox to space elements evenly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am currently working on a project where I have to create four quarters for a year using flexbox. I would like all the quarters to be spaced evenly with the year above quarter 2 and quarter 3. I know I have to use justify-content: space-evenly, but the problem is that quarter 2 and quarter 3 are too close to each other because they are in a container along with the year. I will leave the HTML and CSS here in case you want to see it in js fiddle.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div>Q1</div>
    <div>
      <div class="yearContainer">2022</div>
        <div class="q2q3Container">
          <div>Q2</div>
          <div>Q3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div>Q4</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.yearContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.q2q3Container {
  display: flex;
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to space out q2 and q3 so they have the same space as q1 and q4.
I will leave pictures on how I image it to look like, also a real application of the view. enter image description here.
[image]

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: as mentioned, use grid. you'll only end up with more problems if you won't do it with grid i assume.
This tool always helps me with the initial grid setup, it's pretty amazing: https://grid.layoutit.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `grid` for that design. But if you want to use `flex`, you can use `flex-basis` to define
an area of 25% | 50% | 25% space. Then you can use `justify-content: space-around;` in the Q2, Q3 to evenly space the content. I also used `text-align: center` in main container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  text-align: center;
}

.yearContainer {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.q2q3Container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.fb-25 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.fb-50 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="fb-25">Q1</div>
  <div class="fb-50">
    <div class="yearContainer">2022</div>
    <div class="q2q3Container">
      <div>Q2</div>
      <div>Q3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fb-25">Q4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Unfortunately I have to use flex so grid is out. Thank you once again.

Comment: @TamásKöböl by the way `justify-content: space-evenly;` in .container is not needed. You can remove it. I updated my answer.